# Omitting class name when using a class var from the same class

Tags: swift

Whats the difference when you make a statement like this:

```
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

and this:

```
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
```

Does the `view.backgroundColor` call the class var .white or does swift is UIColor implied when you omit it due to the type of variable? Also what is the convention on these types of statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift can infer the type from the context. In that statement the compiler knows that `self.view.backgroundColor` is a `UIColor`. When you call the class method or property `.white` it automatically calls `UIColor.white`.

The convention is to use the second usage. It's shorter and descriptive enough for pretty much everyone to understand.

Answer (score 2):

There is only a difference of readability. The compiler will do some checking into the type that `backgroundColor` is and determine its an `UIColor`, so it will then use type inference to get the `UIColor.white` and assign it.

As far as standard convention, many people use the shorter type inferances, but that can be really hard to determine what other possible values that exist, especially when using custom types. I use the fully qualified variables, so my code would look like:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

As I believe it is far more readable.