# Why do I see some variables used with leading dot?

Tags: swift, parsing

Consider the following piece of swift code:

```
view1.autoPinEdge(.top, toEdge: .bottom, ofView: view2)
```

What is going on with `.top`, `.bottom`?

1. Why is this seemingly ambiguous way of specifying a variable allowed for parameters?
2. How does swift handle the situation where there are many possible `.top` and `.bottom`?

Comment: This is the job of the compiler. The compiler can infer this automatically.

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943452/omitting-class-name-when-using-a-class-var-from-the-same-class.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The method is (most likely) declared as

```
func autoPinEdge(_ from: UIRectEdge, toEdge: UIRectEdge, ofView: UIView)
```

so the compiler knows that the type of the first two parameters is `UIRectEdge`.

---

The full syntax to call the method is

```
view1.autoPinEdge(UIRectEdge.top, toEdge: UIRectEdge.bottom, ofView: view2)
```

but as the compiler knows (the documentation says *can infer*) the type you can pass only the members

```
view1.autoPinEdge(.top, toEdge: .bottom, ofView: view2)
```

Answer (score 10):

This is just a shorthand way of using an enum value.

for example, using the function...

```
func applyColour(_ colour: UIColor) {
   // apply the colour
}
```

Could be called using the following syntax

```
applyColour(UIColor.red)
```

or

```
applyColour(.red)
```

Because the compiler knows that the function is expecting a `UIColor` parameter. So it can imply the type when you use `.red`

You can also use type inference with static functions and variables like so:

```
extension String {
   static var headerText {
        return "This is the header"
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
headerLabel.text = .headerText
```

or:

```
let heading: String = .headerText
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is much more helpful than "This is the job of the compiler"